# Syntax Error: Identifier 'i' has already been declared JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following error: *Syntax Error: Identifier 'i' has already been declared*
My code intends to remove vowels from any input string.

```
function disemvowel(string) {
    let arr = string.toLowerCase().split("");
  for (let i = 0, i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].includes("a")) {
            arr.splice(i) 
      } else if (arr[i].includes("e")) {
            arr.splice(i) 
      } else if (arr[i].includes("i")) {
            arr.splice(i)
      } else if (arr[i].includes("o")) {
            arr.splice(i)
      } else if (arr[i].includes("u")) {
            arr.splice(i)
      }
  }
  return arr.join("")
}

console.log(disemvowel("stonks"))
```

After correcting for the error, it return the string but anything after and including the first vowel is omitted. How do I omit just the vowels and keep consonants after the vowel?

Comment: `let i = 0,` that needs to end with a semicolon, not a comma

Comment: Great, after fixing that it appears that for test cases, after it encounters the first vowel it omits it and any other character coming after it as well. Any suggestions on how to correct for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo with the `i = 0` here:

```js
...
for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
...
```

and also the last else statement should be else if.

Comment: This should just be a comment. Typos don't need full answers, we just close them.